# K-means boundaries

Tags: cluster-analysis

Is there any way to find boundaries (coordinates) for a x-y data in kmeans clustering. I produced 8 clusters from the xy data which looks like below (each color represent one cluster). I need to get values of the boundaries for each cluster.
[image]

Comment: Read about [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) and [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

Answer (score 0):

The [ELKI](https://elki-project.github.io/) tool that I usually use for clustering will generate the boundaries for you in the visualization. I don't know if it will also output the coordinates to a file though.

It's called a Voronoi diagram, and you need the dual, the Delaunay Triangulation to build it. You can easily find algorithms for that.

Beware that some edges will go to infinity (just imagine two clusters, how does their boundary look like? What are the coordinates of the boundary?)

Note that on your data set, this clustering does not appear to be very good. The boundaries between clusters look quite arbitrary to me.

Comment: The purpose of this work is to find concentration of points. There is a lot of overlaps in points. I did try few more and finally getting what I wish to get around 6 clusters and it looks a lot better than before. Is it possible to get only horizontal & vertical boundaries? if not kmeans; may be some other algorithm?

Comment: Well, clearly e.g. yellow and black are the same concentration of points. The interesting concentrations in the top right, and bottom right, are all in the same gray cluster. The blue also contains multiple interesting concentrations... Maybe you should try OPTICS or DBSCAN or HDBSCAN* instead. Because k-means just does not work on this data set.